# Add authentication system to an existing ASP.NET MVC / C# project

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Currently I have website with a database, three tables and admin functionalities. I want to have a login system for three different types of users (teacher, pupil and admin) and each user is only going to be allowed access of a specific part of the website. Is there any way that I can add a login system without having to re-do the entire project over again?

Comment: Yes, there is a way.  Look into MVC authentication and roles.

Comment: I've tried to look at MVC authentication and roles, but I'm having no luck with it. The only thing I'm having a bit of luck with is doing a form on html with the home controller and the .cshtml files underneath that but i have no idea how to save information to a database using that

Comment: "No luck with it" is too broad for anyone to be able to answer.  You're best bet is to ask a specific question about a problem you're encountering.

Comment: no matter how many times i try to add authentication to the project, it won't connect to the database even if i try and re-do it.